# ubuntu 18.04 vpn mtu How could I make it permanent?

Tags: vpn

vpn it's work but Some sites cannot be accessed
but every time I connect to my VPN, I should run
"sudo ifconfig ppp0 mtu 1500"
How could I make it permanent?

Answer (score 0):

You need to edit the interfaces file present under "/etc/network/"

```
vi /etc/network/interfaces
```

Add the MTU size like below

```
mtu 9000
```

Run the following command

```
/etc/init.d/networking restart
```

I got this information from https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/centos-rhel-redhat-fedora-debian-linux-mtu-size/

Comment: Thank you for solving the problem

Comment: No problem.....